# Export Excel file or Google Document from Android

Tags: android, excel, document

Any ideas to export Excel file or Google Document from Android
Please i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jexcelapi in one of my apps and it works great
http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: can you help me about the paths which can i use to export it on android ?!

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom activity to get a filePath from user selection:

```
  filePath = returnIntent.getStringExtra(FileDialog.RESULT_PATH);
```

when that activity returns I get the path from the intent

Then, when I'm ready to export, I use this to tell my choose where to send it:

```
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse ("file://" + filePath));
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, text));
```